# Date Calculation Total Days

Tags: php

I have this code which is working fine for some dates which I don't understand why, below code should calculate the total days. If I select leavefrom = 2014-04-21 and leaveto = 2014-05-02, it gives me total of 8 days but it should be 9 nine days.

Here is the calendar:-

[image]

```
    function total_day($leavefrom, $leaveto){
        $start_date=strtotime($leavefrom);
        $cur_day=$start_date;
        $end_day=strtotime($leaveto);
        $count=0;

        $holiday=array("2014-05-01"=>"Labour Day", "2014-08-31"=>"Independence Day", "2014-12-25"=>"Christmas");

        while(1){

            //echo date("Y/m/d", $cur_day)."<br/>";
            $cur_day=$cur_day +(3600*24);
            //echo $count."S--".date("Y-m-d", $cur_day)."<-----E--".$end_day;


            $day_of_week=date('w', $cur_day);
            //echo "day_of_week-----".$day_of_week."<br/>";
            if ($day_of_week == 0 || $day_of_week == 6) {
                //No Operation
            }else if(array_key_exists(date("Y-m-d", $cur_day), $holiday)){
                //echo "Holiday because of ".$holiday[date("Y-m-d", $cur_day)];
            }else{
                $count++;
            }
            //echo "Total day--".$count."<br/><br/>";

            if(($cur_day==($end_day+(3600*24)))||($cur_day>$end_day)){
                break;
            }

        }
        //$count = $count + 1;
        return $count;

    }

$totaldays = total_day($leavefrom, $leaveto);
```

Comment: Why not use the standard `DateTime::diff` (or `date_diff`)? See this to achieve what you need: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy
Nope I can't, I need to count from the starting date till the ending date, if we count it, it will actually produce different value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no error there. From `2014-04-21` to `2014-05-02` there are 11 days out of which 2 weekends and 1 holiday (`2014-05-01`). Thus making `11 days - 3 days = 8 days`

But If you want to include the starting date as well. Then you can use this:

```
while(1){       
    if($cur_day>$end_day){
        break;
    }
    $day_of_week=date('l', $cur_day);
    if (in_array($day_of_week,array('Saturday','Sunday'))) {
        // NO operation
    }else if(array_key_exists(date("Y-m-d", $cur_day), $holiday)){
        // NO operation
    }else{
        $count++;
    }
    $cur_day=$cur_day +(3600*24);

}
```